# Trigger that updates just the inserted row

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I'm trying to create a simple trigger using TSQL (or SQL Server 2008). The problem is: my current trigger is updating the entire table. This was fine for a while, but now the table has more than 20k rows. So I want a trigger that only updates the rows that are being inserted.

Here's my current simple trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trig_MyPplUpdate
ON [Persons]
FOR INSERT
AS
Begin
 Update Persons
    set MyFile = NULL
    where Len(MyFile) < 60
End
```

I think I'll have to use either the "inserted" table or the `row_number` function ordered by the primary key. Any ideas?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If it is necessary to use a trigger here at all I would use an `INSTEAD OF` trigger to adjust the values pre-insert and avoid the need to `JOIN` back onto the base table and Update them afterwards.

```
CREATE TRIGGER trig_MyPplUpdate
ON [Persons]
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
  BEGIN
      INSERT INTO Persons
      SELECT foo,
             bar,
             CASE
               WHEN Len(MyFile) >= 60 THEN MyFile
             END
      FROM   Inserted
  END
```

Comment: Ok so let me get this straight: An "Instead of" trigger means that BEFORE any insert happens my trigger will fire? I honestly don't understand what you wrote (select from inserted? Then MyFile?) and I'll have to research more about this on the internet but I think that this is what I want =-). If you want to make my life easier you can explain a little bit more but what you wrote is the starting point that I needed. Thanks a ton!

Comment: @Gaspa79 - Yes. SQL Server will take your insert statement and construct the `inserted` pseudo table that has all the insertable columns from `[Persons]`. Then you select from that to do the actual insert into the base table. You didn't provide your table structure so I had to make up the other column names.

Comment: Ok great! I'm trying it right now. I assume that the When Len(MyFile) >= THEN Myfile is because if that condition isn't satisfied it won't insert the column value, therefore it will be null. On the other case, when it's satisfied, it will insert the column (MyFile).
Thanks a lot man, seriously =-).

Comment: @Gaspa79 - Yes, there is a default `ELSE NULL` if the condition isn't met.

Comment: I'd recommend to explicitly specify the column names in your INSERT statement - that way, you won't get any nasty surprises if your table suddenly gets an additional column ...

Comment: @marc_s it would raise an error which is what you would want to happen in this situation. It reminds you that you need to add the new column to the trigger. Rather than the `instead of` trigger silently ignoring the new column and so you getting `null` or the column default value instead of any value explicitly supplied.

Answer (score 21):

You need to join the `Inserted` pseudo table in your `UPDATE` statement. Always be aware that SQL Server fires the trigger **once per statement** and that statement can very well modify/insert **multiple rows** at once - so your `Inserted` table quite likely will contain more than one row - just need to keep that in mind when you write your trigger.

Try something like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trig_MyPplUpdate
ON [Persons]
FOR INSERT
AS
    UPDATE dbo.Persons
    SET MyFile = NULL
    WHERE Len(MyFile) < 60
    AND PersonID IN (SELECT DISTINCT PersonID FROM Inserted)
```

or use whatever unique column (your primary key) you have to get exactly those rows that have been inserted.