# SQL update inserted row with trigger

Tags: sql, t-sql, triggers, sql-insert

I'm trying to update a just inserted row in SQL with a table trigger. Below is the trigger. It seems this only updates the already inserted rows and NOT the just inserted row. What am I doing wrong?

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[TRG_DIM_Employee]
ON [dbo].[DIM_Employee]
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    UPDATE DIM_Employee
    SET ParentEmployeeKey = i.EmployeeKey
    FROM INSERTED i
    WHERE DIM_Employee.EmployeeId = i.EmployeeId
END
```

Comment: which version of MS SQL are you using?

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2012 - 11.0.5556.0 (X64) 
 Oct 31 2014 16:50:24 
 Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
 Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.3 <X64> (Build 9600: ) (Hypervisor)

Comment: Why not just have a default value in SQL?   You want a trigger of overwrite even if they supply a value for ParentEmployeeKey?

Comment: Because not only the just inserted row must be changed but all rows having that particular EmployeeId must be updated.

Comment: Could you post a sample of the data in the employee table?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Trigger that updates just the inserted row](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8987097/trigger-that-updates-just-the-inserted-row)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can recognize, this is old join syntax but is functionally equivalent.  I set up a quick test but can't repro this issue, seems to work as expected.

FYI you should move to using proper JOIN syntax, this old ANSI-89 standard is already discontinued in some forms in SQL 2012.

Answer (score 0):

Your update statement is not quite right. You need to JOIN your table with the inserted table rows.

```
ClientID int,
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[TRG_DIM_Employee]
ON [dbo].[DIM_Employee]
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    UPDATE emp
    SET emp.ParentEmployeeKey = i.EmployeeKey
    FROM  DIM_Employee emp
    JOIN INSERTED i on emp.EmployeeId = i.EmployeeId
END
```

More examples of doing an update join [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1293330/how-can-i-do-an-update-statement-with-join-in-sql).

Comment: I've tried this and the outcome is exactly the same as the original statement.