# How to create a trigger that only updates one row

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers

I researched my question, but still don't know what the syntax would be. This did not answer it: [Trigger that updates just the inserted row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8987097/trigger-that-updates-just-the-inserted-row)

[image]

Using Oracle SQL Developer, in this Employees table, assuming ID is the primary key, how should a trigger be created for the update of the second record to change Alice's region to "West"?

So far, I have:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER employees_trg on employees
WHERE ID = 2
FOR INSERT
AS
    UPDATE dbo.employees
    ....
```

Comment: The answer to your question is that many databases do not allow a trigger to fire on the same table which called the trigger.  So you might need to find a workaround, such as a stored procedure.  By the way, what database are you using?

Comment: What DBMS  you're using? It is not quite clear from your  question, but answer depends on it.

Comment: I edited my question to mention Oracle SQL Developer. Thanks.

Comment: The linked question is for SQL Server which has a **completely** different concept for triggers (for one: it doesn't have row level triggers)

Comment: a_horse_with_no_name Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I understand is when someone do update of row with Id = 2 you want to force that region is West. You can do it with:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER employees_trg 
  BEFORE UPDATE on employees FOR EACH ROW
begin
if (:new.id = 2) then
  :new.region := 'West';
end if;
end;
/
```

Comment: but he is asking to update it ,. your above example if and update add will cause `Mutating error`

Comment: @Moudiz why do you think that? Agreed that Kacper has used `BEFORE INSERT` instead of `BEFORE UPDATE` but fixing that wouldn't cause a mutating table error.

Comment: OK I fixed it to update you're right. No mutating error as I'm not doing insert just overwriting new value. @Moudiz